# How to fix this error - Automatically redirect subdomain to folder path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

HOW CAN I FIX THIS ERROR ?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::%1 !^/([^/]+).*?::\1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

[error > image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RV5RW.jpg)

When i open this link : abc.example.com

Automatically read folders

```
/abc/sub/
```

How can i change it to

```
/sub/abc/
```

Comment: It is unclear where `sub` is coming from -- Do you have any other redirects set up?

Comment: @Gerrit0 yes ..  *.example.com  to  /public_html/sub ... http://i.imgur.com/MgHoV80.jpg

Comment: It shouldn't be `/sub/abc/` either. `/sub/` is already the document root of your vhost and is mapped to `/` from an URL perspective. Unless you try to access `abc.example.com/sub`, in that case the current rewrite rule would map that to `YOUR_USER/public_html/sub/abc/sub/`. Actually, the `sub` part in the URL you currently get is a bit of a mystery, unless you are able to provide the full server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out Apache Virtualhosts.

From the documentation:

> mod_rewrite is not the best way to configure virtual hosts. You should first consider the alternatives before resorting to mod_rewrite. See also the "how to avoid mod_rewrite document.

For information on using Apache Virtualhosts to mass-remap hosts to folders, see this guide:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/mass.html

(Specifically, see the section on "Simplified Dynamic Virtual Hosts")

I acknowledge that I'm not explicitly answering the question that you're asking, but I am trying to point you to an easier (and more supported) way of accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: thank you :) , but i can't open httpd.conf file in ssh :/

Comment: Oh that's unfortunate.

This guide should be able to tell you how to do it with mod_rewrite [see Dynamic Virtual Hosts Using mod_rewrite], but I can't add much because I haven't done it that way.  
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/vhosts.html

Good luck!